# Ractive populating select list, null values from json

Tags: json, select, ractivejs

I have a problem with dropdowns in ractive with null values from json. It's best explained in the actual example in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shrekuntu/x5w5v2wy/)

Basically, list of workstations, when chosen, populates the rest of the form with values.

Problem is for example if you go on workstation 1 and then to workstation 3 which has department_id=null, and department dropdown does not reset to 
 `<option value=''>` 
but stays on the one prior to change. Trying to set value of w to null before set to actual id does not help at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `null` and an empty string aren't the same. Ractive couldn't find a `null` in `<select>`. You can set `value` to `null` for the first option so that Ractive can find a `null` in `<select>`. http://jsfiddle.net/x5w5v2wy/10/

```
<option value='{{ null }}' selected>--Pick a Department--</option>
```

This is possible because Ractive allows a limited set of expressions inside `{{ }}`, and luckily, `null` is allowed.